# Axios is not installing

Tags: terminal, axios

I am trying to install axios for the elastic search course, but for some reason, I am getting this:
[6 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kIah.png)

When I try running the command (npm audit fix--force), I end up getting this:
[More errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjhHG.jpg)
[More errors again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxIqH.png)

And then, when I try running the same command again, I get this:
[same number of errors I started with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLTi2.png)

So, when I try running the command multiple times, I end up in a loop of errors. Please, help!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code :

```
npm i axios --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Hello, Reza. I tried this, but it still kept giving me the same errors.

Comment: Actually, I found out the project still works even with the errors. Thanks though, Reza.